# не работает команда virtualenv ~/envs/tensorflow

Tags: python, pip, установка, tensorflow, virtualenv

хочу установить `tensorflow` в `virtualenv`,

- установил `virtualenv` (командой `pip install virtualenv`),
- потом дал команду `mkdir envs` (на диск C),
- далее по руководству нужно написать `virtualenv ~/envs/tensorflow` и
- после этой команды оно дает:

  - `virtualenv` не является внутренней или внешней
    командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

так делаю, ибо хочу установить tensorflow, но он не работает, если я устанавливаю через pip, выдает ошибки:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации 
                               библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).
 Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

поэтому я хочу скачать `tensorflow` в `virtualenv`, но и так не могу.
помогите, пожалуйста